# JSON Schema: How to correctly use oneOf reference in json?

Tags: json, enums, jsonschema

Using the following site: http://jeremydorn.com/json-editor/ and pasting the following code in the schema part:

```
 {
  "type": "object",
  "Title": "Pets",

  "definitions": {
    "petType": {
      "oneOf": [
        {
          "$ref": "#definitions/cat"
        },
        {
          "$ref": "#definitions/dog"
        }
      ]
    },
    "cat": {
      "sounds": {
        "enum": [
          "meow",
          "ghh"
        ]
       }
    },
    "dog": {
      "sounds": {
        "enum": [
          "woof",
          "grr"
        ]
      }
    }
  },

   "properties": {
    "productType": {
      "type": "string",
      "enum": [
        "cats",
        "dogs"
      ]
    },

    "sounds": {
      "type": "string",
      "enum": [
        { "$ref":"#definitions/petType" }
      ] 
    }


  }
}
```

The goal is to have a second drop down with the matching pet sounds. But how to correctly make the reference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently this is an [open issue with the spec](https://github.com/json-schema-org/json-schema-spec/issues/331).

One way of looking at it is that you would need a "$ref" pointer based on a ["$data" pointer](https://github.com/json-schema/json-schema/wiki/$data-(v5-proposal)) which isn't currently supported.

Unfortunately, in the meantime arrangements like this need to be handled with application logic rather than a straight schema AFAIK.